# AngularJS number input endless loop

Tags: angularjs

I have a number input, and if the number is increased or decreased then a function should be invoked:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="amountOfInterval" ng-change="vm.changedAmountOfInterval(amountOfInterval)" />
```

In this case I get an endless loop.  When the number is increased, then `changedAmountOfInterval` is invoked, number is increased and so on.

My question now would be how to prevent this?

Comment: Could you post the definition of the changedAmountOfInterval function?  Likely you are changing amountOfInterval in that function triggering another change that then causes changedAmountOfInterval to be called again.  Basically, you should not change the value of amountOfInterval in that function without a guard to prevent the endless loop

Comment: or provide a jsbin code...

Comment: By definition, changing the ng-model in ng-change will generate an endless loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="number" ng-model="amountOfInterval" ng-change="amountOfInterval = amountOfInterval + 1" />
```

This code works absolutely normal:
http://plnkr.co/edit/f2SgkbCc0gretZlDFWi0?p=preview

Ng-change will not trigger after you change model, only if user changes it.

I think you have some kind of watch on this variable which also calls this function, something like:

```
$scope.$watch($scope.amountOfInterval, function() {
    $scope.amountOfInterval++;
})
```

This will give you endless loop.